# Newark Airport (EWR) to Manhattan - Air Train suspended

Tags: transportation, new-york-city, ewr

I'm going to NY in June 2014 while AirTrain will be suspended due to repair work. Is there still any not-depending-on-traffic way to go to Penn Station, NewYork?

[AirTrain Newark Service Suspension](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-airtrain-suspension.html)

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-from-newark-airport-to-penn-station-new-york-e?rq=1

Comment: Helicoper service used to be relatively affordable (lands you at the East River in lower Manhattan), but it looks like it's pretty expensive now, even by NYC standards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Philadelphia to Newark Airport without AirTrain](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26314/philadelphia-to-newark-airport-without-airtrain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any other rail options from the airport itself, so you'll necessarily be on the road (and subject to traffic) at least part of the journey.

The nearest train station in that direction is Newark Penn, and the link you posted includes options for getting there by bus.  You could also take a cab.

Comment: There are not.  Airtran is the only option.